# Can the dust cause DDR RAM errors?

Tags: memory, hardware-failure

After my system has began unstable I have checked its memory using memtest86+ tool. It has found several thousand memory errors. Then I've opened PC case and pulled out the installed 2 DDR2 sticks, blew the dust off, then installed them back. Again, checked the memory using memtest86+ and it haven't found any memory error anymore! I wonder if the dust can cause RAM errors?

Comment: You have proven that dust could in theory cause memory errors through your actions.

Comment: By removing and re-inserting the modules you have rasped the pins of the module and the socket, removing fouling. This can also be the reason why it works now.

Answer (score 4):

It is possible.  Dust usually isnt made of materials that can pass current, although its been known to occur.  Also, dust can build up an electrostatic charge which can cause issues if its in contact with the memory's connectors.

Also, dust inhibits airflow.  Usually it takes a lot, but a buildup of dust can cause the memory to overheat and have errors.

Or, it could just be that the memory wasnt seated properly and when you pulled them out and put them back in, that solved the issue.  Sometimes parts just work their way loose...

Comment: `Or, it could just be that the memory wasnt seated properly and when you pulled them out and put them back in, that solved the issue. Sometimes parts just work their way loose...` I wonder if that applies to [my question here](https://superuser.com/questions/1579994/can-unplugging-your-ram-stick-and-plugging-it-back-in-solve-ram-errors-problems), but I don't know how the parts would have possibly worked themselves loose in a 1 year old laptop that is just sitting on a desk most of the time.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, i have had a stick of ram prevent my PC from starting, it had dust buildup because it was the closet to the CPU fan.

as Keltari said, dust usually isn't made of conductive materials, however, it makes an excellent place for moisture to sit (My issue occurred after about a week of rain)